# how to set model extend in models.json?

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

I use new loopback, in my models.json :

`"customer": {
  "options": {
    "extend": "User"
    },
  "properties": {}
}`

But after run and explore, the customer model isn't extend user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"base" should be used instead of "extend". See [docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Model+definition+reference#Modeldefinitionreference-Options).

```
"user": {
  "options": {
    "base": "User",
 },
 "properties": {}
}
```

We could consider to support both "base" and "extend".

Comment: I had to adjust like that, but still does not work. Is need to initialize the app.js?

Comment: Did you create the project using 'slc lb project' command? If so, the app.js will load models.json. Please see an example at: [https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-mysql-example/blob/master/models.json#L9](https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-mysql-example/blob/master/models.json#L9). For further questions, it's probably better to use [LoopBack mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs).